# How to map 2 maps with a function in Scala?

Tags: scala, mapping

When `c` map equals a function of `a` map I can calculate it as

```
val a: Map[T, U] = ...
def f(aValue: U): V = ...
val c: Map[T, V] = a.map(f)
```

but what if `c` map equals a function of both `a` and `b` as arguments? For example if `a`, `b` and `c` are `Map[String, Int]` and a `c` values are to equal corresponding `a` values raised to powers specified by corresponding `b` values?

Comment: This is really unclear.  Can you give an example of some input data and expected output?  Also, can you fix the code sample you have so that it would actually compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
val a = Map('a -> 2, 'b -> 3)
val b = Map('a -> 4, 'b -> 5)
a.map{ case (k, aVal) => (k, aVal + b(k)) } // Map('a -> 6, 'b -> 8)
```

Comment: Note that this version calls Map.apply, which will throw a NoSuchElementException if b doesn't contain a mapping for one of a's values.  Map.get, on the other hand, returns an Option.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
val a: Map[String, Int] = Map("a" -> 10, "b" -> 20)
val b: Map[String, Int] = Map("a" -> 2,  "b" -> 3)
def f(a: Int, b: Int): Int = math.pow(a,b).toInt // math.pow returns a Double

val c = for {
  (ak, av) <- a        // for all key-value pairs from a
  bv <- b.get(ak)      // for any matching value from b
} yield (ak, f(av,bv)) // yield a new key-value pair that results from applying f

// c: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 100, b -> 8000)
```

Comment: I mean I need `f` to take 2 arguments getting the first from `a` and the second from `b` to produce a `c` value.

Comment: Thank you too, a very nice way to know too.